# How to receive broadcasts of RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have the following broadcast receiver:

```
public class MyRingModeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logger.iLog("In my Receiver");
    }
}
```

I then have a service that onCreate does the following:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED");
    registerReceiver(new MyRingModeReceiver() , filter);
```

When I place a call to the emulator and use the volume keys to modify (silence) the ringer
nothing happens. Any ideas of what it is that i am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the Intent Ringer_MODE_CHANGED is not called when you silence a ringer using the phone app ... Only when you modify the ringer outside of a phone call.