# Listen for ringer muted on incoming call

Tags: android

i need to know in a background task if the user mutes an ongoing ringing with the volume button. so the call comes in and the phone starts ringing. the user then mutes this ringing by clicking one of the volume buttons. neither RINGER_MODE_CHANGED nor ContentObserver on system settings work here since the volume does actually not change nor does the phone change its ringer mode.

any ideas?

Thx 
Simon

Comment: did you figure this one out yet?

Comment: nope. i even digged around in the android source code, but it seems to be not possible...

Comment: it used to be possible to detect, but as of android 2.3 it broke. i put in a couple of bug reports, but they havent been touched...